# How to set the zooming feature in alert dialog while using imageview in it

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, android-alertdialog

I used an **ImageView**  in the **alertdialog** to show an image. Image is successfully loading in the alertdialog. I want to add additional feature of zooming the image. 
I tried but no result.

**My code for alert dialog is as below**

```
private void loadPhoto(String url) {
        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_image, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)//load images into imageview
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_file)
                .into(image);
        imageDialog.setView(layout);
        imageDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        imageDialog.create();
        imageDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: show what you "tried a lot"

Comment: @pskink I tried a lot means I searched a lot in SO. so should i post my browser history here?????????